# Computing the double integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos k\xi \cdot u(\xi ) \, dkd\xi$

Tags: integration

Everyone. I have a question as follows:

$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos k\xi \cdot u(\xi ) \, dkd\xi, $$

where $u(\xi) = {a}_{0} \operatorname{sech}^{2} \left( \sqrt{\frac{a_{0}}{6+4a_{0}}} \, \xi \right)$, and  $a_0$ is a constant.

And the variables $k$ and $\xi $ are in structured rectangular grid.
($u(\xi) \to 0$ as $\xi \to \pm \infty $)

I'm trying to find its analytic solution.

Could you please help me for that?

Many thanks!!^^

Comment: I edited your posting so that the title better reflects your question. Hope this is to your liking. Anyway, in the given order of integration, the integral does not converge simply because the inner integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(k\xi)\,\mathrm{d}k$ does not converge. There are several options to resolve this issue. First, we may interchange the order of integration, which then results in a convergent integral. Alternatively, we may regularize the integral in an appropriate way. Either approach gives the value $a_0 \pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment, the integral does not converge in its current form. So let us consider the iterated integral with the order of integration reversed:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(k\xi)u(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\mathrm{d}k, $$

where $c = \sqrt{a_0/(6+a_0)}$. Although a direct computation is available, a more natural solution is to relate the integral to Fourier transform of $u$. Indeed, if we define $\mathcal{F}[u](\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x)e^{-i\xi x} \, \mathrm{d}x$, then it is well-known that the inverse transform $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is given by $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[u](x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(\xi)e^{ix\xi} \, \mathrm{d}\xi$, and so,

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(k\xi) u(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\mathrm{d}k = \pi (\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}u)(0) = \pi u(0) = \pi a_0. $$

Alternatively, we may adopt some regularization method. In this approach, we consider the following function

$$ I(\epsilon) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(k\xi)e^{-\epsilon k}u(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi\mathrm{d}k $$

for $\epsilon \geq 0$. Of course, $I(0)$ corresponds to the original integral. Also, from the previous remark, we know that $I(\epsilon) \to I(0)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. (This is due to a version of Abel's theorem.) Moreover, for $\epsilon > 0$ the integrand of $I(\epsilon)$ is integrable, and so, we may apply the Fubini's theorem to compute

\begin{align*}
I(\epsilon)
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(k\xi)e^{-\epsilon k}u(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}k\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&\qquad = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2 + \xi^2} u(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi 
\stackrel{(\xi = \epsilon s)}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + s^2} u(\epsilon s) \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

Then letting $\epsilon \to 0^+$ and applying the dominated convergence theorem to interchange the order of integration and limit gives

\begin{align*}
I(0)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{1 + s^2} u(\epsilon s) \, \mathrm{d}s
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + s^2} u(0) \, \mathrm{d}s
= \pi a_0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I appreciate for your astonishing comments!! It's really great!